# Android: Multi fragment design with different number of tabs in each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, material-design, android-tablayout

I have an app which consists of one activity. All the other screens are implemented with fragments. Depending on which item was selected in the navigation drawer the corresponding fragment is loaded. One of the views (fragments) has an alternative way of doing things. Scanning a QR code or manually filling in a form. I don't know if it violates design best practices because this view should contain tabs but other views do not.

http://cd8ba0b44a15c10065fd-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/d6/40b7173a09619d47c144ebf444feeb.png http://cd8ba0b44a15c10065fd-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.r23.cf1.rackcdn.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/d3/f50fe292739faa65f70fef82a46a34.png

I am also using `AppBarLayout` because this control implements the material design (elevation) out of the box. If I implement the `TabLayout` within the `PairingFragment` then visually the tabs are placed under the toolbar's shadow. So I have moved the `TabLayout` to the `MainActivity`.

**MainLayout.axml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/MainDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/MainToolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  android:id="@+id/MainTabLayout"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/MainContentRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/MainDrawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawerlayout_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Note:** This is a Xamarin project. I do not think that it is difficult  for a Java developer to read C# code.

**MainActivity.cs**

```cs
using Support4 = Android.Support.V4;
using Support7 = Android.Support.V7;

[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Support7.App.AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private TabLayout mainTabLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mainRelativeLayout;
    private NavigationView mainDrawerNavigationView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainLayout);

        this.mainTabLayout = this.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.MainTabLayout);
        this.mainRelativeLayout = this.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.MainContentRelativeLayout);
        this.mainDrawerNavigationView = this.FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.MainDrawerNavigationView);

        this.mainDrawerNavigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            this.ShowFragment(new DefaultFragment(this.mainTabLayout));
        }
        else
        {
            // Configuration change. The last fragment was recreated by the runtime
            // using the fragment's default constructor.
        }
    }

    public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.DefaultDrawerMenuItem)
        {
            this.ShowFragment(new DefaultFragment(this.mainTabLayout));
        }
        else if (menuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.PairingDrawerMenuItem)
        {
            this.ShowFragment(new PairingFragment(this.mainTabLayout));
        }

        this.mainDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer(Support4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
        return true;
    }

    private void ShowFragment(Support4.App.Fragment fragment)
    {
        Support4.App.FragmentManager fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;
        fm.BeginTransaction().Replace(this.mainRelativeLayout.Id, fragment).Commit();
    }
}
```

**PairingFragment.cs**

```cs
public class PairingFragment : Support4.App.Fragment
{
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    public PairingFragment()
    {
        // This constructor is needed by the runtime because of
        // calling base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState) within
        // MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) calls
        // this constructor.
    }

    public PairingFragment(TabLayout tabLayout)
    {
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.tabLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PairingFragment, container, false);

        Support4.View.ViewPager pairingViewPager = view.FindViewById<Support4.View.ViewPager>(Resource.Id.PairingViewPager);

        pairingViewPager.Adapter = new PairingPagerAdapter(this.ChildFragmentManager);
        this.tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(pairingViewPager);
        return view;
    }
}

public class PairingPagerAdapter : Support4.App.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public PairingPagerAdapter(Support4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager)
        : base(fragmentManager)
    {
    }

    // Removed code for readability
}
```

As you can see the `TabLayout` is injected via constructor to the fragments. Fragments who do not have tabs set the visibility of the injected `TabLayout` to `ViewStates.Gone`.

This works good enough as long as there is no configuration change. If there is one then the activity is destroyed an re-created. In this case the fragments are not injected via the constructor and the code breaks because of `NullReferenceException`.

What should I do? Should I change the design of the app? I don't think this is a design flaw. At times when there is a configuration change should I get the actual fragment and then inject the `TabLayout` via method or property? This will work today because there is always one fragment. But what happens when I need tomorrow more than one fragment? Checking if each fragment "can handle a `TabLayout`" does not seem to be right.

Regards Yavuz